# Defining a range for 2 private subs that have been merged

Tags: vba, excel, merge

I have 2 private subs that have been merged into the code below. the 2nd part of the code i need to define the logic for the range. The issue i am facing is my second code does not specify a range so i am unsure on how to define the range? and my VBA knowledge is not that great!  can someone help me enter this information?

The Codes before merging are:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Range([H2], Cells(Rows.Count, 
    "H").End(xlUp)))

    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    rng.Offset(, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]<>"""",R1C[6] & ""-"" &" & 
    "TEXT(COUNTA(R2C[-1]:RC[-1]),""0000"") & ""-"" & R1C[7],"""")"
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Code 1 is using P1 and O1 to populate an automatic number in column I if information is provided in H Code 2:

```
Private Sub Move_blanks_To_Bottom(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
   If Target.Column <> 9 Then Exit Sub
   Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 11).Sort 
   key1:=Range("I1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

Code 2 is using column I and sorting the values so if there is a value in I it moves the row to the next available line where column I is completed effectively if cell I is blank the row is moved to the bottom.

The merged code is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

   Application.EnableEvents = False

  'Do logic for this first range
   Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
   Set rng = Intersect(Target, Range([H2], Cells(Rows.Count, 
   "H").End(xlUp)))
   If Not Intersect(rng, Target) Is Nothing Then
      rng.Offset(, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]<>"""",R1C[6] & ""-"" &" & 
      "TEXT(COUNTA(R2C[-1]:RC[-1]),""0000"") & ""-"" & R1C[7],"""")"
   End If

  'now do logic for the second range (move_blanks_to_bottom)
   '2nd LOGIC HERE
   If Target.CountLarge = 1 And Target.Column = 9 Then
        Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 11).Sort 
        key1:=Range("I1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
  End If

  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your sorting command is fine though it is pretty complicated because it compresses a series of operations in one command. With this command you sort a range from column A to column K (=11) and from row 1 to last used row, with header. You could split this command with these simpler ones:

```
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim r As Range

lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' find row of last non-blank cell in column A
Set r = Range("A1").Resize(lastrow, 11)   ' set the exact data range
r.Sort key1:=Range("I1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

but this will do the same as in your code 2.

You might need to know that if you break the command into 2 lines you need to terminate the line with an `_` like this:

```
Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 11).Sort _
    key1:=Range("I1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

otherwise the compiler will treat them as separate commands and will drop a Syntax error message.